# Set a checkbox as 'checked' when an if condition is fulfilled in php

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox

I want to mark a checkbox as 'checked' automatically when an if condition is fulfilled. Here is an example of the if condition-

```
if($wp_session['tdwa_verification_checks'] < 2){

}
```

And the checkbox is-

```
<input class="input-text a-save" type="checkbox" id="chkboxclicked" name="tdwa-foreign-citizen" value="1">
```

I am trying with this but its not working.

```
if($wp_session['tdwa_verification_checks'] < 2){

    echo '<input class="input-text a-save" type="checkbox" id="chkboxclicked" name="tdwa-foreign-citizen" value="1" checked>'; 

}
```

I would appreciate if anyone can give me a clue. Thanks :)

Comment: Could you provide the full PHP code?

Comment: Umm, actually I'm working on an existing WordPress plugin and the code is too long.

Comment: Understood...you say it is "not working", what exactly is happening? Do you see the checkbox, but it is not checked when it should be? Do you not see a checkbox at all?

Comment: What does `var_dump($wp_session['tdwa_verification_checks']);` outputs?

Comment: I can see the checkbox, but it is not checked when it should be. I am confused about the way I coded inside if condition is correct or not!

Comment: ($wp_session['tdwa_verification_checks']); will check and verify and 'tdwa_verification_checks' == 1 means it is not verified. And then the checkbox will be marked. Thats the plan :)

Comment: What happens when you only print the check box with `checked` attribute, without the if condition?

Answer (score 0):

A couple issues. One is that you're wrapping you're entire checkbox inside an `if` statement. Another is that it's very strange to check for a boolean value by comparing it to `less than 2`  as you'll generally compare it to equal `1`. Another is that `chkboxclicked` is a very vague ID to say that least, you should probably change that to something more similar to the name. You should also add the closing slash since checkbox inputs are void elements.

Now, looking at your code, you're also checking `$wp_session['tdwa_verification_checks']` but the input name is `tdwa-foreign-citizen`, are you sure that the key you're checking in `$wp_session` is correct?

Lastly, WordPress has a neat function called [`checked()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/checked) that will compare and check values for you if applicable. This is how you should probably be using it in your markup:

```
<input class="input-text a-save" type="checkbox" id="tdwa-foreign-citizen" name="tdwa-foreign-citizen" value="1" <?php checked( $wp_session['tdwa_verification_checks'], 1 ); ?> />
```

Answer (score 0):

you're printing the checkbox correctly, you have to verify to value for

```
$wp_session['tdwa_verification_checks']
```

you can find the value by doing

```
echo json_encode($wp_session['tdwa_verification_checks']);
```

once you find the value you can compare correctly